# MySQL-string concatenation with a php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want to combine the variable $name with the "%" so i can search for names that begin the value of $name.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$get_search_results_q= "SELECT * FROM `users`.`info` WHERE `info`.`fullname` ='$name'+'%' ";
```

Comment: What's wrong with `='".$name."%'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This u need

```
$get_search_results_q= "SELECT * FROM `users`.`info` WHERE `info`.`fullname` LIKE '$name%' ";
```

Comment: Worked as expected!Thanks mate :)

Comment: Why it returns nothing when i type something that doesn't exist in DB?

Comment: because its only return if found any record that begin as u defined

`LIKE 'keyword%'` for all record begin 'keyword'

Comment: No i mean nothing.mysql_query doesn't show anything.It don't return even false...

Answer (score 2):

```
$get_search_results_q= "SELECT * FROM `users`.`info` WHERE `info`.`fullname` ='$name%' ";
```

Note that your code is open to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), you should have a look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: I know Ende thanks for the reply.At the moment i build the main idea,later i will go to mysqli()